# Make css animation to run infinitely

Tags: html, css, animation

Having this html/css snippet:

```css
.triangle-four {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 150px solid transparent;
  border-right: 150px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 250px solid rgb(20, 97, 27);
  margin-top: -120px;
  animation-name: example;
  animation-duration: 4s;
}

@keyframes example {
  0% {
    background-color: red;
  }
  25% {
    background-color: yellow;
  }
  50% {
    background-color: blue;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: green;
  }
```

```html
<div class="triangle-four"></div>
```

I want to make it run infinitely and tried to do it like this:

```
 animation-duration: 4s infinite;
```

It doesn't work, the animation is not working anymore even thought this is what is recommended to do on [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation.asp).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I remove `animation-name: example; animation-duration: 4s;` and add this `animation: example 5s infinite;` it will fix your problem.

another solution it just to add this without removing anything :

```css
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
```

```css
.triangle-four {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 150px solid transparent;
  border-right: 150px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 250px solid rgb(20, 97, 27);
  margin-top: -120px;
  animation: example 5s infinite;
}

@keyframes example {
  0% {
    background-color: red;
  }
  25% {
    background-color: yellow;
  }
  50% {
    background-color: blue;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: green;
  }
  }
```

```html
<div class="triangle-four"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following css should fix it:

```
 animation-duration: 4s;
 animation-iteration-count: infinite;
```

---

```css
.triangle-four {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 150px solid transparent;
  border-right: 150px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 250px solid rgb(20, 97, 27);
  margin-top: -120px;
  animation-name: example;
  animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes example {
  0% {
    background-color: red;
  }
  25% {
    background-color: yellow;
  }
  50% {
    background-color: blue;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: green;
  }
```

```html
<div class="triangle-four"></div>
```

Of course, the end of the animation "jumps" to red, but that is the effect described by your animation. If that was not intended, you can simply add this css:

```
animation-direction: alternate;
```

Answer (score 0):

On the link provided, it says that the animation property is a shorthand for multiple animation properties.

You have to specify the `animation-name` and the `animation-duration`. You may then add the `animation-iteration-count`.

```css
.triangle-four {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 150px solid transparent;
  border-right: 150px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 250px solid rgb(20, 97, 27);
  margin-top: -120px;
  animation: 4s example infinite;
}

@keyframes example {
  0% {
    background-color: red;
  }
  25% {
    background-color: yellow;
  }
  50% {
    background-color: blue;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: green;
  }
```

```html
<div class="triangle-four"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

just add

`animation-iteration-count: infinite;`

it will solve the issue